# Output Text between 2 lines using filtering option

Tags: emeditor

We are using EMEditor for logfile analytics in huge textfiles. We have following requirement.
In the logfile, there are a lot of tables in this format:

```
+----------------------+
|Column1|Column2|Colum3|
+-------+-------+------+
|Data1  |Data2  |Data3 |
|Data4  |Data5  |Data6 |
+-------+-------+------+
| Number of Records: 2 |
+----------------------+
```

The text between the header and footer is very dynamic; it could be 0 or x-lines between it.

I would use the filter option in this way, that I input for example `|Column1` using the start filter and `| Number of Records:` as end filter. EMEditor should filter all records between start- and end filter (inclusive line with the found filter patterns).

I have seen, it's currently only possible to output lines above and under the filter pattern, but this is no practicable way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `+` and `|` characters are used only for tables, you can filter tables by these characters. To do this, you can click the **Advanced Filter** button in the **Filter** toolbar, click **Add** button and enter `+`, click **Add** button again to enter `|`, and set the **Logical Disjunction (OR) to the Previous Condition** option to the second item in the list. Finally, click **Filter** button.

**Updates**

Download EmEditor v20.0.902 or later, and use the **Begin Filter** and **End Filter** options in the **Advanced Filter**.
[image: Advanced Filter]

If you would like to use a macro, this is a macro for you:

```
filters = document.filters;
filters.Clear();
filters.AddFind( "|Column1", eeFindReplaceCase, eeExFilterBegin );
filters.AddFind( "| Number of Records:", eeFindReplaceCase, eeExFilterEnd );
document.filters = filters;
```

You can run this macro after you open your data file. To do this, save this code as, for instance, `Filter.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your data file, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while your data file is active.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The problem is, that there exists different tables with different number of columns and column header labels in the logfile.

We want using as start filter, for example above table the column header label "Column2" to filter tables from one type; end filter the same as in my entiere post.

Results should output all the "found" tables in above format (except first and last line = +----------------------+).

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot specify "start filter" or "end filter" in EmEditor. If you want to exclude any lines with `+----------------------+`, you can add an entry to the Advanced Filter, and set the **Negative** option.

Comment: First, we purchased EmEditor for the main feature: speed; great product!

Are there any chances to implement such feature in a future version of EmEdior?. I know there are many factores to that have to be considered:
Benefit for other customers, complexity of the requirements, time for implementing, side effects for current implementation and much other things.

Comment: The next version will include **Begin Filter** and **End Filter** options in the **Advanced Filter** dialog box. I will release the next beta shortly.

Comment: I'm extremely excited right now. Thats exactly what we need. I tried them and it works perfectly. Thank you very much. Great support.

Answer (score 0):

Does this HAVE to be done via filter? Is it not possible to isolate/select just the table data using the standard Find method? e.g. Ctrl-F. Click on Advanced and make sure *"Regular Expression "." can match Newline Characters* is selected. Set the *Additional lines to Search for RegEx* to a number higher than what you expect the largest table.

Click OK and then Find (Regular Expressions Selected):

**(?<=^\+----------------------\+.)\|.+?(\| Number of Records[^\|]+\|)**

Click "Select All" and this should hopefully capture just the tables and you can now do what you want with it (Click the Extract button, copy, cut, etc.).

Comment: thx, i would try this and report the result, this could take a while :)