# Display number of filitering results sets

Tags: emeditor

According to my question

[Begin-/Endfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232259/output-text-between-2-lines-using-filtering-option)

Is it possible in EmEditor to display the number of filtered results sets (could be equal to number of lines, if not using the Begin-/Endfilter) in the status bar of EmEditor; i found no options in the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you filter, how about searching for the **end filter** with the **Count Matches** option?

[image: Find dialog - Count Matches option]

If you use a macro, I added the `Find` line to the last of the previous macro. You can use this macro instead:

```
filters = document.filters;
filters.Clear();
filters.AddFind( "|Column1", eeFindReplaceCase, eeExFilterBegin );
filters.AddFind( "| Number of Records:", eeFindReplaceCase, eeExFilterEnd );
document.filters = filters;
document.selection.Find( "| Number of Records: ", eeFindCount | eeFindReplaceCase );
```

You can run this macro after you open your data file. To do this, save this code as, for instance, `Filter.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your data file, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while your data file is active.

Before you run this macro, please deselect the **Show Execution Time** option in the **Status** page of the **Customize** dialog box.

[image: Customize dialog - Status page - Show Execution Time option]

Comment: Yes, thats the solution; sorry for the unecessary question, thank you very much.

Comment: No, not a problem. This is just a workaround, but the next version will improve the status bar info with the number of begin/end filter sets.

Comment: I've released v20.1 beta 3 (20.0.903), which addressed this issue.

Comment: Thank you, noticed :); translation is currently only in english; i will open soon a post in some cases in the gui german tranlation is not done or is incorrect.

Comment: Localizations (translations) in beta versions are not supported, but should be corrected at official versions (such as v20.0.0, v20.1.0, etc.). If GUI translations of official versions are still incorrect, please let me know

Comment: In 20.0.906, all languages were localized, so you are welcome to correct any translation mistakes.